# sbt - migrating IntelliJ Play application to 2.3.x

Tags: intellij-idea, playframework, sbt

I am starting to work with IntelliJ/Scala/Play  I created a new Play2 application and it works just fine.  I have been trying to migrate it from Play 2.2.1 to 2.3.5 but I am getting an error

can not resolve symbol enablePlugins

My files look like

build.properties:

```
sbt.version=0.13.5
```

plugins.sbt:

```
logLevel := Level.Warn

resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

// Play plugin
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.3.0")

// web plugins
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.3.1")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-less" % "1.0.0")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-coffeescript" % "1.0.0")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-rjs" % "1.0.1")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-digest" % "1.0.0")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-gzip" % "1.0.0")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-mocha" % "1.0.0")
```

build.sbt:

```
import play.Project._

name := "Play2App"

version := "1.0"

//playScalaSettings

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava SbtWeb)
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: You have `sbt-plugin` twice, is that normal? Shouldn''t it read `addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.3.5")` for 2.3.5?

Comment: Also are you now using `activator` and not `play` console?

Answer (score 0):

You miss a comma between "PlayJava" and "SbtWeb"

```
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava,SbtWeb)
```